Something like in_array but with an array of needles
I currently have this code:
if (in_array('help', $argv) || in_array('-help', $argv) || in_array('--help', $argv)) {
    echo "USAGE: fixhosts v0.1 [--help] [--version|-v|-ver] [\\s] [--enable] [--disable]\n";
    die();
}

How can I write it so it runs in_array foreach needle - without using a loop.
So...
$needles = ['help', '-help', '--help'];

if(in_array($needles, $argv)){
    // found
}

I know I can do:
$needles = ['help', '-help', '--help'];
foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    if (in_array($needle, $argv)) {
        // do something
        break;
    }

But is there a built in function that does that? I want it to only execute once if there is a match, so if multiple $needles match multiple $argv value, it just returns true.

I think you want array_intersect()
